# ServiceNow Ticket Creation from JIRA

Tags: api, jira, jira-rest-api, servicenow

I know that it is possible to create a JIRA defect from ServiceNow, however is it possible to create a ServiceNow Problem Ticket from JIRA?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, you should develop a plugin which creates your desired items in your Servicenow instances over SOAP.
Servicenow offers SOAP webservices for every table.

We created such a JIRA plugin and we have a lot of JIRA<->ServiceNow interactions.

This answer is very high-level but what do you expect from a one sentence question? :)

Comment: I appreciate it. Where can I find this plugin?

Comment: Was going to suggest something similar.
If you create a plugin in JIRA to post JSON via the ServiceNow REST API its easy enough.
You could create an import table in ServiceNow to receive this JSON, and create a valid mapping onto the table of your choice

Answer (score 1):

You can crete Inbound Web Service, Exhibiting ServiceNow outside.

You can refer to this wiki:
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Web_Services#Inbound_Web_Services&gsc.tab=0

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Getting_Started_with_REST#gsc.tab=0

According to endpoint references that can assign scripts (as in this case the opening of a ticket).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create ServiceNow issues in Jira. There are different ways to get this done. One way is using the Jira plugin. But here creating tickets or updating the tickets is a little complicated. I use the third-party tool called automate.io to get this done automatically. Here you can go to [connect jira and servicenow](https://automate.io/integration/jira/servicenow) apps and improve the productivity of your team.